# str_get_html and simply html dom

Tags: php

way after str_replace function $img is empty and secont $img->find('img') function show error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type simple_html_dom as array in D:\wamp\www\test.php on line 7

   <?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$img_html = str_get_html('hhtml tekst html tekst <img src = "img.png" /> ad sad');

foreach($img_html->find('img') as $element)
    $img[] = $element->src . '<br>';

$img_html = str_replace($img[0], 'n-'.$img[0], $img_html);    

foreach($img_html->find('img') as $element2)
    echo $element2->src . '<br>';
?>
```

Comment: Please clarify what are you trying to achieve, because this code is one big mess

Answer (score 2):

Is this really what you're aiming to do?

```
foreach($img->find('img') as $element)
    $img[] = $element->src . '<br>';
```

$img is an object on the first foreach -loop, but then you're trying to access $img as an array, which is causing the error. Are you accidentally using the same variable name for two different things?

Comment: Which line is causing the error, still line 7, or some other line, and is the error message exactly the same? This: $img_html = str_replace($img[0], 'n-'.$img[0], $img_html); is again overwriting your object variable, which you try use as an object in the next statement and that can cause a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `str_get_html` before `str_replace` as:

```
$img_html = str_get_html('hhtml tekst html tekst <img src = "img.png" /> ad sad');

foreach($img_html->find('img') as $element)
    $img[] = $element->src;
$img_html = str_get_html(str_replace($img[0], 'n-'.$img[0], $img_html));

foreach($img_html->find('img') as $element2)
    echo $element2->src . '<br>';
```

Also check that you have given correct path in require_once( 'simple_html_dom.php');